# How to display one set of buttons when I click on one button of the main set/array of buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display a new set of buttons when I click on one button of the current set.
I am not able to implement an `onclick` function and I don't want to introduce new HTML pages per click. I want to display a new set of buttons when I click on one of the category buttons.

Here is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<body style="display:grid">
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
  "use strict"
  fetch("https://storage.googleapis.com/android-tv/android_tv_videos_new.json")
    .then(function(resp){
      return resp.json();
    })
    .then(function(data){
      let data2= data.googlevideos
      let category_names = []
      let video_list0 = []
      for(let i=0; i<data2.length; i++){
        category_names.push(data2[i].category);
        //video_list0.push(data2[i].videos[j])
            for(let j=0;j<data2[i].videos.length;j++){
            video_list0.push(data2[i].videos[j])
          }         
        }
        const filterstudio = (array , studios) => array.filter(task => task.studio===studios);
                const category1videos = filterstudio(video_list0,"Google+");        
        
        category_names.forEach(button);        
        function button(item) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<button style='display: grid; width: 100px'>" + item + "</button>";
          }
        category1videos.forEach(myFunction);        
        function myFunction(item) {
            document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML += "<button style='display: grid; width: 100px'><a href='"+item.sources+"'>" + item.title + "</button>";
        }
        

    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code, the currently category_names button set is created and then the category1 videos button set is created too. I want to show category1 video buttons when I click on category 1 and on the same HTML page too. I tried `onclick= style.display` to be none and calling category1videos.forEach(myFunction), but it is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Code Output:
[image: Code output]

Comment: Hi, if possible can you share a link to codepen? I am unable to recreate this

Comment: i was starting here: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-lovelace-vyyvs?file=/index.html
please make this at least console.log(resp) on line 15. your code is not even executed before the fetch promise

Comment: I couldn't see where it called the function button and the function myFunction and what argument it gave in it ?

Comment: Deniz please install an extension if you are using chrome, https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-orign-cors-changer/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc, when this is switched on, the code will work for sure, its a cors issue that doesnt allow the code run

Comment: CanUver, please look at this command, category_names.forEach(button);  this code calls in button function which makes an element from the json data first array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
fetch("https://storage.googleapis.com/android-tv/android_tv_videos_new.json")
    .then(function (resp) {
        return resp.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {

        let data2 = data.googlevideos
        let category_names = []
        let video_list0 = []

        let container = document.getElementById("demo")

        container.innerHTML = ''

        for (let i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {

            const item = data2[i]
            const category = item.category
            
            const categoryCode = category.replace("'","")
            
            container.innerHTML += `<button  onclick="showVideos('${categoryCode}')" style="display: grid; width: 100px">${category}</button>`

            const videos = data2[i].videos

            let videoContainer = `<div class="videos-container" style="display:none" data-target="${categoryCode}">`

            for (let j = 0; j < videos.length; j++) {
                const video = videos[j]

                videoContainer += `<button><a href="${video.sources}">${video.title}</button>`

                if (j === videos.length - 1) {
                    videoContainer += '</div>'

                    container.innerHTML += videoContainer

                }
            }

        }
    })


function showVideos(target) {

    const el = document.querySelector(`[data-target="${target}"]`);
    const isHidden = el.style.display === "none"
    el.style.display = isHidden ? 'block' : 'none'

}
```

```css
.videos-container{
 padding:.5em;
 margin:.5em;
 border:1px solid #000;
 border-radius:15px;
}
.videos-container button{
 display:inline-block;
 margin:.5em;
 padding:.2em;
 
}

a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```